# How to encode h.264 live stream to RTP packet with Java

Tags: java, android, h.264, rtsp, rtp

I am developing an application for Android OS, and I need a real-time decode video stream from the camera, that encoded with h.264 codec, convert frame data to RTP packet and sent packet to server.

For a start, may try to implement on PC read video from the pre-recorded video file (mp4 with h.264) from HDD to simplify the development and debugging.

Is there a ready-made solution? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please select correct answers as answered.

Comment: There is no correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Spydroid. It pipes the camera input into the H.264 encoder and turns the output into RTP packets:

http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/source/browse/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/rtp/H264Packetizer.java